# Matlab creating mat files which names are written in the variable

Tags: matlab

I have a variable 'b'. Inside of b, I have 27X1 cell. In every cell there is some characters for example in 1x1 there is asdf, in 2x1 there is dfgh it's going on like this. I want that matlab creates mat files which names are asdf, dfgh and assign scalar valurs to these files. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a loop going through the "`b`"cellarray containing the "filenames" and:

1)get the filename by converting the content of the `i-th` to a string by using "`char`" function

2)call "`save`" specifying the filename (see previous point) and the list of scalar you want to save in it (in the question you did not specified which scalar to be saved)

```
% Generation of cellarray
b{1,1}='asdf'
b{2,1}='dfgh'
b{3,1}='third_mat_file'

% Loop through cellarray
for i=1:length(b)
% Get the filename
   a=char(b(i))
% Generate a dummy scalar to be saved
   m=rand;
% Save the scalar in the ".mat" file   
   save(a,'m')
end
```

Hope this helps.